# What is a good reference for automatic (algorithmic) differentiation?

Tags: derivatives, reference-request

Could someone kindly provide me with a good reference about automatic  differentiation? I have already had a look at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), but I would need a book or article, which gives a better theoretical understanding. It would also be helpful if I had a step by step guide to understand the concepts.

Comment: The difficult step is the simplification, not the differentiation. Say you are given $f(z) = \sin((\exp((\frac{ z^2}{\tan(z)}+2)^{1/2}+\log(z^8))^4)$. You have to see how this is a **tree** of mathematical expressions, and how differentiating each node of the tree isn't difficult.

Comment: I really do need some reference material on this though. Any good references (books, articles) are most welcome

Comment: For what ? Do you understand what I wrote ? See this [example](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/math-parser-using-lambda-expressions/) for $4  \sin(x + 1) + 3$. Do you see why it is easy to differentiate such an expression tree ?

Comment: Are you interested by what is called "exact gradients computation" in the framework of optimization ? If yes, see for example the article "COMPUTATION OF EXACT GRADIENTS IN DISTRIBUTED DYNAMIC SYSTEMS" by Yuri Evtushenko

Comment: @user1952009 Yes I see that a parse tree of the mathematical expression is built in the example you provided. So I guess you can apply the chain rule to the tree. However there are still many unknowns as far as I am concerned. I am looking for a good book explaining how to implement AD in practice in a language such as C++.

Comment: Aren't the works cited at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Literature enough? See also http://www.autodiff.org/?module=Introduction&submenu=Selected%20Books.

Comment: I read the entire wiki page and still not clear what automatic differentiation is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try also these simpler papers:

- [The arithmetic of differentiation](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689402) by L. B. Rall
- [A simple automatic derivative evaluation program](https://doi.org/10.1145/355586.364791) by R. E. Wengert

Comment: Many thanks for the links to the articles. This is exactly what I needed to get started!

Comment: This new paper is also quite good: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.05031.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is quite old but I'm surprised no one has suggested the following two books:

1. [Evaluating Derivatives - A. Griewank & A. Walther](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898717761)

   - Both authors are well known for their work regarding automatic differentiation.
2. [The Art of Differentiating Computer Programs - Uwe Naumann](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611972078)

   - The author also explains the code aspects in detail (in C++).

This paper is also a nice overview:

- [Automatic differentiation in machine learning: a survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05767)

Answer (score 3):

Another valuable source, both for the theoretical background and for code, is Sebastian Walter's PhD thesis:

> [Structured Higher-Order Algorithmic Differentiation in the Forward and Reverse Mode with Application in Optimum Experimental Design](http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/dissertationen/walter-sebastian-2011-12-07/PDF/walter.pdf)

The Python implementation of the ideas in the above thesis is called [`Algopy`](https://pythonhosted.org/algopy) and is fairly easy to understand.

Algorithmic differentiation, which is an exact numerical approach for calculating derivatives of computer programs, is different from symbolic differentiation of expression trees.  Reverse-mode AD has to work on graphs necessarily. 
 Any implementation that scales to real world code and problems is actually exceedingly difficult to implement.  Pretty much all existing systems have significant limitations of one sort or another.

Answer (score -3):

You won't find a reference because for a programmer the problem is almost trivial. However, you can find many students projects implementing this problem in every language.

---

The steps are :

- parsing, transforming the text $\sin(z)+4 \exp(2\log(z))$ to a binary tree. At first, you can avoid this step by constructing binary trees directly :

  ```
   new add(new sin(z),new mult(4,new exp(new mult(new constant(2),new log(new var('z')))))
  ```
- differentiating the binary tree to return a new binary tree
- simplifying the obtained mathematical expression (this step is of course the most difficult, and is still a research problem)

Once you have your binary tree of mathematical expressions, differentiating is really not complicated.

A node will be of the form $u+v, u-v, uv, u/v, u^v$ where $u,v$ are two mathematical expressions, or $f(u)$ where $f$ is an elementary function. Each of those cases is easy to differentiate :

$$(u+v)' = u'+v', \ (uv)' = u'v+v'u, \ (u/v)' = u'/v - uv'/v^2,\  u^v = u' u^{v-1} + v' \log(u) u^v , \  (f(u))' = u' f'(u)$$

Programatically in C++ you'll have a class`add` and a class `sin`

```
 class add : expression {
     expression * u,* v;
     void print() {  .... }
     expression * differentiate() {
         return new add(u->differentiate(),v->differentiate());
     }
 };

  class sin : expression {
     expression * u;
     expression * differentiate() {
        return new mult(u->differentiate(),new cos(u));
     }
 };
```

And the other operators and elementary functions follow the same idea.

Comment: there is a little mistake in the formula for the derivative of $f(u)$.

Comment: It seems you're talking about **symbolic** differentiation. But **automatic** differentiation is something else (see the Wikipedia link in the question).

Comment: @HansLundmark Once you have the expression tree, it is easy to compute the symbolic derivative, or to backpropagate a gradient. I'm quite sure this is what the OP didn't know